# Nuxt PM2 CPU up to 100%

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, pm2

Hello guys can you help me please!
My app use up to 100% CPU when a lot of users go to my app.
I tried a lot of things, and my config turned into a mess
This is my nuxt.config.ts.

```js
import type { NuxtConfig } from '@nuxt/types';
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const mainConfig: NuxtConfig = {
  ...
  build: {
    cache: true,
    optimization: {
      minimize: true,
      runtimeChunk: true,
      concatenateModules: true,
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        minSize: 30000,
        maxSize: 0,
        minChunks: 1,
        maxAsyncRequests: 20,
        maxInitialRequests: 3,
        automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
        name: true,
        cacheGroups: {
          vendors: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            priority: -10,
            chunks: 'all'
          },
          default: {
            minChunks: 2,
            priority: -20,
            reuseExistingChunk: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    filenames: {
      app: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].js' : 'js/[name]/[contenthash].js'),
      chunk: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].js' : 'js/[name]/[contenthash].js'),
      css: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].css' : 'css/[contenthash].css'),
      img: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'img/[contenthash:7].[ext]'),
      font: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'fonts/[contenthash:7].[ext]')
    },
    extend(config, { isClient }) {
      config.externals = [
        function (context, request, callback) {
          if (/(pdfmake)/.test(request) || /(xlsx)/.test(request)) {
            return callback(null, 'commonjs ' + request);
          }
          callback();
        }
      ];
    }
  },
  router: { ... },
  modules: [ ... ],
  server: { ... },
  watchers: {
    webpack: {
      ignored: ['**/node_modules', 'node_modules']
    }
  }
};

export default mainConfig;
```

The application does not stand up to 2000 users and breaks,
I really dont know what to do! :(
Maybe you will can help me?

Comment: Is your app full static or SSR served? Also, what is happening on your website with those 2000 users? A 100% CPU usage can from a lot of things (memory leak, poorly optimized code, heavy task etc...), best way is to connect to the instance and try to see which services is taking that much (you can SSH to it, right?).